# Reusing image slider with ID

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a pure html/css image slider on a webpage which was working great until I tried to put a second slider on the same page. In the code snip below you will see that IDs are used to map labels to sections to allow the transition between elements. Using IDs in this way breaks when you try to put a second slider on the page. I have attached a full plunkr below with example code. Is there a simple way to adjust this to allow having 2 sliders on the page that operate independently?

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-1" checked />
<li class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-image">
    first slide
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-controls">
    <label for="img-3" class="prev-slide">
      <span>&lsaquo;</span>
    </label>
    <label for="img-2" class="next-slide">
      <span>&rsaquo;</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jxg1OsvfHFbHQPb49TDm?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because both of your slider's input radio have the same name (`radio-buttons`), which allows you to choose one item only from all `radio-buttons` inputs. Each slider must have its own input radio with different name.

```css
/* Styles go here */

ul.slides {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

ul.slides input {
    display: none;
}


.slide-container {
    display: block;
}

.slide-image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

    .slide-image img {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

.carousel-controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 199;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 400px;
    color: #000;
}

    .carousel-controls label {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0 20px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .2s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.slide-image:hover + .carousel-controls label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-controls label:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-controls .prev-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-controls .next-slide {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 199;
    text-align: center;
}

    .carousel-dots .carousel-dot {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

input:checked + .slide-container .slide-image {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .carousel-controls label {
    display: block;
}

input#img-0:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-0,
input#img-1:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .carousel-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    opacity: 1;
}


input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            first slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            second slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-3" />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            third slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <div class="carousel-dots">
          <label for="img-1" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
          <label for="img-2" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
          <label for="img-3" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="carousel">
      <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons2" id="img-4" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            first slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons2" id="img-5" />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            second slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons2" id="img-6" />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide-image">
            third slide
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-controls">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev-slide">
              <span>&lsaquo;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next-slide">
              <span>&rsaquo;</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <div class="carousel-dots">
          <label for="img-4" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
          <label for="img-5" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
          <label for="img-6" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://plnkr.co/edit/KeJGhctcsPcJScajsylk?p=preview

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" id="img-4" checked />

<label for="img-4" class="carousel-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
```

Here is an adjusted version. You were using id's multiple times which is a no-no. IDs are unique and should only be used on 1 element.

When I change the second slider id's to 4-5-6 instead of the same 1-2-3 as above, it works fine. Just take a look on how you are displaying the side arrows and you should be good to go. I would look into showing the arrows on hover over the element.

Comment: My mistake - forgot to save. Corrected the link. I also explained the solution as well.

Comment: That still doesn't make both sliders work unfortunately. If you click a dot in one of them it makes that slide load in that slider while making the slide in the other slider disappear. I am asking is there a way to make both function independently on the page at once using only HTML/CSS. Need like a CSS variable or something so CSS can track them independently.

Comment: @dialex got it there from my answer. Second radio group can't have the same name as the first.